# jquery validation - ignore fields blank/not required until a value is entered for other validations

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jQuery validation - validating on blur:

```
$('input, select, radio, checkbox').blur(function(){
        $("#createAccount").validate().element(this);
});
```

If a user is tabbing through the form, and the field is optional, the field is validated as ok (and a class is added, changing the color etc. of the input field)

What I would like to do is to ignore validation for an empty field not required.

My current ignore is only for `:hidden`

```
ignore: ":hidden",
```

and when I tried:

```
ignore: ":hidden, .ignore",
```

this would throw an error on when any field was focused that had the class ignore. So that almost works, except if you ignore the field then the other validations on that field don't trigger. So the field is optional, but there are still validations on it. I just don't want it to trigger the success validation on an empty optional field.

thanks!

***Edit***

So the logic should be: onblur if empty and not required then ignore - if not empty then run the validations attached to that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to accomplish this:

For an input that needed to be ignored until it had a value I added a class to the input - "ignore"

```
$('.ignore').blur(function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="") {
         $(this).parent().removeClass("inputSuccess");
        }
    });
```

In the function, if an input has the class ignore and no value has been entered, then I remove the valid class I set in the validate call. When a value is entered, the normal validations will trigger on those items.

Answer (score 2):

Add following line before the validate line

```
if($(this).val()=="")
{
 return;
}
```

For text field it is "". For Select it might be "0" or any other value that you have specified for first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a different css class for the not required field and ignore the fields with those classes. For example

```
ignore: ".ignore"
```

where `ignore` can be used like

```
<input type="text" class="ignore" value=""/>
```

Just my thoughts.

Comment: yes, but I also want `:hidden` to be ignored as well - so I need both, and validation throws an error when you have more than one ignore identified (can't find documentation around this)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how validate works but  you can add a flag/class to the fields you dont want to validate and just ignore those

Update

ok so if the optional empty field has ignore class then

```
$('input, select, radio, checkbox').blur(function(){
    if( !($(this).hasClass('ignore') && $(this).val()=="")) {       
        $("#createAccount").validate().element(this);
    }
});
```

the code might not be 100% correct but the concept is there, only validate if the field is not empty and the field does not have .ignore class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not quite getting the question, but here's an example that looks like what you are trying to do with 1 ignored text box and 1 hidden text box: http://jsfiddle.net/brianmat/wJveQ/2/

**Relevant jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("form").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below' : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
            $("div.error span").html(message);
            $("div.error").show();
        } else {
            $("div.error").hide();
        }
    },
    ignore: ".ignore, :hidden",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("div.error").hide();
        form.submit();
    }
});

});​
```